# Liferay Document Library Services

Tags: soap, service, liferay, document

I need a method like `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileAsStream(...)`.However, I am using SOAP services of Liferay in my application.

Is there anyway to get a file stream about the document or getting file like byte array or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Liferay's SOAP services, you can't use the "Local" services, but have to use [DLFileEntryService](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLFileEntryServiceUtil.html) instead. (notice the missing "Local" part of the name).

Local services are available only through Java and don't involve permission checking. The remote services do involve permission checking and are available through SOAP as well, requiring authentication.

Re your comment: I see that there's no `getFileAsStream` available through SOAP (as `InputStream` can't be serialized properly). You might need to write your own service endpoint that handles the data. On the implementation side, you can forward to `DLFileEntryService`. Make sure that you have an upper limit of file size, as you're not streaming.

How do you do this? Write your own plugin, add an empty entity to a new Liferay Service and implement the method you need. As the implementation just reformats the data but in general forwards to `DLFileEntryService`, it should be really simple.

Comment: I could not find any function about getting file content in there.I am getting only file Informations etc. How can i implement this?

Comment: Hi Olaf,                                        DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileAsStream(...) not working in my server I have s3 bucket configuration for document and media. This method perfectly working without any issue where s3 not configured. Does this require any extra configuration.?

Answer (score 0):

If you basically want to convert DLFileEntry into File then you can use another method.

File file = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFile(user.getUserId(),dlFileEntry.getFileEntryId(), dlFileEntry.getVersion(), true);